# C# bug - new created project cannot debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm new to C# and using Visual Studio 2019 to learn C#.

Now after I create a new project I cannot run and debug it. The code is very simple.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OErqb.png)

But the start debugging is dark. Also, I found there is no project in the solution.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSfUj.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4Dxw.png)

I just find that when I create a new project, something is missing in the project folder.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKzXz.jpg)

When I want to open the .csproj file, it gives me a prompt: unable to locate the .NET SDK.

Really appreciate someone who can point out what should I do or give any clues.

Comment: You've just opened the Program.cs file. Go open the .sln file.

Answer (score 1):

You have a single .cs file open.  To compile it into an application, create a "New Console Project" in Visual Studio and copy this code into the resulting Program.cs.  In the future, open up the *.csproj or *.sln files to work with the project, not just the individual .cs file.  Good luck!

Comment: I created console project and get this code. They are the same. I tried to open it with .sln files but still get the same result.